# Icon Request - Not found in list

Tags: font-awesome

I searched over for few icons as per my menu listing but can't find in the list.

1. Gadget icon
2. [Augmented Reality](https://www.igyaan.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/augmented-reality-20x20.png) icon
3. Virtual Reality icon
4. [Wearables](https://www.igyaan.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/smartwatch-01-20x20.png) icon
5. Classic [Notepad](https://www.igyaan.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/verified-text-paper-20x20.png) icon

Answer (score 0):

:-)
I too am mssing some icons. Fortunately there's a process for that - but you'll have to post [here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues). I don't know which "menu listing" you used, I typically go to https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery , but did not find anything either.